# Debian Packaging with JavaSwing?

Tags: debian, package-management, java

On my `Ubuntu 14.04` machine I am developing a `java swing` application and I'm compiling it with `oracle java version "1.7.0_80"`

In the `myapp-1.0.0/DEBIAN/control` file I put the following information:

```
Package: myapp
Version: 1.0.0
Section: Java
Priority: optional
Architecture: i386
Depends: openjdk-6-jre
Suggests: 
Conflicts: 
Replaces: 
Maintainer: name
Description: Sample application
```

in the `postinst` file I put:

```
chmod 777 /usr/local/myapp/myapp.sh
```

and `myapp-1.0.0/usr/local/myapp/myapp.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -jar myapp.jar
```

I successfully build the package and installed on my system.

I could find the menu entry for my application, but when I click it, it does not open my swing application.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your java is visible in the system
and your jar path is fully defined:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=<your java SDK>/bin:$PATH

java -jar </full/path/to/app/>myapp.jar
```